# Don't understand the line $\int_{B(0,1)}\eta(y)\int^1_0\int_V \mid Du_m(x-\epsilon ty)\mid dxdtdy\leq \int_V\mid Du_m (z)\mid dz$ in Evans PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is Evan's pde page 287, stating that $\int_{B(0,1)}\eta(y)\int^1_0\int_V \mid Du_m(x-\epsilon ty)\mid dxdtdy\leq \int_V\mid Du_m (z)\mid dz$

Here $u_m$ is smooth, compactly supported in $V$ and $\eta$ is a mollifier whose integration is 1.

Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $t\in[0,1]$, $y\in B(0,1)$, the equality $\int_V|Du_m(x-\epsilon ty)|\,dx = \int_V|Du_m|$ holds because $u_m$ is supported in $V$. As $0\le\eta\le 1$ everywhere, the integration of $\int_{B(0,1)}\eta\int_0^1\,dt\,dy = c$ holds for an appropriate dimensional constant $c>0$. Thus by Fubini's theorem
$$
\int_{B(0,1)}\eta(y)\int_0^1\int_V|Du_m(x-\epsilon ty)|\,dx\,dt\,dy \le c\int_V|Du_m|.
$$
(In short, the answer is translation invariance and the definition of $\eta$.)

Comment: ah that makes sense. thank you! Should the equality in the first line inequality?

Comment: @MinSeokSong; yes I think the first equality may be an inequality.